# Assigning specific element of multidimensional array in url in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

My goal is to get specific element/value from a multidimensional array and assign them in a URL in loop. I have already tried and was able to get elements in the array but this displays all elements. I only want to get specific, like `nid` and `field_x` values.

This is my link structure: `http://localhost:8080/$nid/$field_x`

**Expected result:**

```
http://localhost:8080/123/one
http://localhost:8080/789/three
```

This is my sample `var_dump` result

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(38) {
    ["nid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(123)
      }
    }
    ["vid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(456)
      }
    }
    ["field_x"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["target_id"]=>
        string(6) "One"
      }
    }
    ["field_y"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["target_id"]=>
        string(2) "Two"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(38) {
    ["nid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(789)
      }
    }
    ["vid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(321)
      }
    }
    ["field_x"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["target_id"]=>
        string(6) "Three"
      }
    }
    ["field_y"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["target_id"]=>
        string(2) "Four"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This helps me getting elements in a multidimensional array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811491/access-specific-element-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: In the previous link you talk about the question or the answer?

Comment: Your answer seems working to me. And I appreciate your fast response. I just have one concern, because its giving me an array results. I just want to a list of urls, not within array. BTW, previous link is already talking about an answer.

Comment: Ok, but, why didn't you comment or close the previous question if the answer helped you? Thanks. What do you mean by "list of urls"? The first part of the answer `echo` the URLs, which form do you need please?

Comment: I think the one who answered on that topic modified my original question and include his answer, which I believe I accepted lastweek, and he removed it in the answers list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `foreach()` and get the data using `$values['nid'][0]['value']` or `$values['field_x'][0]['target_id']`:

```
foreach ($result as $values) {
    $nid = $values['nid'][0]['value'];
    $field_x = $values['field_x'][0]['target_id'];
    echo "http://localhost:8080/$nid/$field_x" ;
}
```

Will outputs:

> http://localhost:8080/123/One
>   http://localhost:8080/789/Three

You probably want to do something else than an echo, so you can create a new array:

```
$urls = [];
foreach ($result as $values) {
    $nid = $values['nid'][0]['value'];
    $field_x = $values['field_x'][0]['target_id'];
    $urls[] = "http://localhost:8080/$nid/$field_x" ;
}
print_r($urls);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! This is what im looking for. Sorry I didnt tried `echo` at first which is what I want to achieve!